# Обмен данными 1c 7.7+ с интернет-магазинами

Tags: 1с, xml

Как происходит интеграция инернет-магазина с 1c? Как эту интеграцию организовать? Какой механизм? Какие +/-? Если есть приличная статья (искал, не нашел) - линканите плз.
Спасибо

Answer (score 2):

Пример кода для отправки POST-запроса из 1ски 77 к php - скрипту. Наверняка поможет! Я так делал, формируя в 1ске строку в формате json, и отправляя ее в скрипт, который сохранял все в базу данных. Замечательно все работает! Успехов :)

```
WinHttp=СоздатьОбъект("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1");
WinHttp.Option(2,"Windows-1251");                   
WinHttp.Open("POST","http://sta.gov.ua/control/uk/vat/search",0);

// Вторым параметром передаем GET-данные 
// param1=value1&param2=value2"

// WinHttp.SetProxy(0,"192.168.1.1:3128");// Задаем параметры своего прокси сервера
// WinHttp.SetCredentials("ProxyLogin","ProzyPassword",1);

// Задаем параметром логин и пароль         
// Если прямое соединение то так в коментах и оставлем :)        
WinHttp.SetRequestHeader("Accept-Language", "ru");
WinHttp.SetRequestHeader("Accept-Charset","Windows-1251");
WinHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Language", "ru"); 
WinHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Charset", "Windows-1251"); 
WinHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=Windows-1251");

ПараметрыПОСТ = "isJuridical=1" + "&individualCode="+СокрЛП(Контрагент.ЕДРПОУ);

// Параметром передаем POST-данные для страници тут как раз            
WinHttp.Send(ПараметрыПОСТ);

// Дальше или сохраняем страницу в файл
Текст = СоздатьОбъект("Текст");
Текст.ДобавитьСтроку(WinHttp.ResponseText());
Текст.Записать(КаталогИБ() + "otvet.htm");
```

Answer (score 1):

Существует формат CommerceML. Открытый стандарт, разработанный несколькими российскими и зарубежными компаниями.
Ссылочки: http://v8.1c.ru/edi/edi_stnd/90/ http://www.commerceml.ru/